# How to update shared library file

Tags: clang, ld, libtool, unix-ar

I'm trying to add a `.lo` object file compiled through `libtool` with `clang` into a shared library file.

```
$ libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile clang -c newobject.c -shared
```

Is there an equivalent command to

```sh
$ ar r libmylib.a newobject.o
```

for shared libraries?

Alternatively, is there a way to dump all the `.lo` files that are already contained in a `.so` file so I can re-create tne shared library, say, using this command?

```sh
$ libtool --mode=link ld -soname libmylib.so -o libmylib.so.1 libmylib.so.0 newobject.o
```

Comment: No; you have to relink the whole library with all the object files.

Comment: Is there a way to extract the remaining object files from the old shared library file?

Comment: Not that I know of. There might be tools on some platforms to do so, but I’ve not heard of anything like that existing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to incrementally alter a shared library.  You need all the component object files and rebuild the shared library from those each time.

I don't know of a way to extract object files from a shared library.